# How to render youtube field?

Tags: entities, files

How can I render a Youtube field to get the full code for embedding?

```
field_view_field('node', $o, 'field_testvideo', $display)
```

What are the settings for $display?

Comment: Found a solution width the Media Youtube Module:            print theme('media_youtube_video',$o->field_testvideo['und'][0]);

Comment: you should put your solution as an answer and accept it so that this gets removed from the unanswered question page.

Comment: there is better solution as I described in my answer. mine will work on multiple fields on multilingual sites ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$display should be one of view modes (full, teaser, rss or ...) or display setting array:

```
$display = array(
    'label' => 'hidden',
    'type' => 'file_rendered',
    'settings' => array(
        'file_view_mode' => 'media_original',
    ),
);
```

Comment: Where do you put this code?